# React Native - How to Take Multiple Snaps and Select Them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to take a snap using React Native. I have the code to snap the image. Now I want to take multiple snap photos and select them exactly like in WhatsApp (the tick UI).

I'm new to React Native. It will be helpful if someone helps me do it.

Here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLecT.jpg) for reference that how I exactly want it to be.

**camera.page.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';

import styles from './styles';
import Toolbar from './toolbar.component';
import Gallery from './gallery.component';

export default class CameraPage extends React.Component {
    camera = null;

    state = {
        captures: [],
        capturing: null,
        hasCameraPermission: null,
        cameraType: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
        flashMode: Camera.Constants.FlashMode.off,
    };

    setFlashMode = (flashMode) => this.setState({ flashMode });
    setCameraType = (cameraType) => this.setState({ cameraType });
    handleCaptureIn = () => this.setState({ capturing: true });

    handleCaptureOut = () => {
        if (this.state.capturing)
            this.camera.stopRecording();
    };

    handleShortCapture = async () => {
        const photoData = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
        this.setState({ capturing: false, captures: [photoData, ...this.state.captures] })
    };

    handleLongCapture = async () => {
        const videoData = await this.camera.recordAsync();
        this.setState({ capturing: false, captures: [videoData, ...this.state.captures] });
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const camera = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        const audio = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING);
        const hasCameraPermission = (camera.status === 'granted' && audio.status === 'granted');

        this.setState({ hasCameraPermission });
    };

    render() {
        const { hasCameraPermission, flashMode, cameraType, capturing, captures } = this.state;

        if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
            return <View />;
        } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
            return <Text>Access to camera has been denied.</Text>;
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <View>
                    <Camera
                        type={cameraType}
                        flashMode={flashMode}
                        style={styles.preview}
                        ref={camera => this.camera = camera}
                    />
                </View>

                {captures.length > 0 && <Gallery captures={captures}/>}

                <Toolbar 
                    capturing={capturing}
                    flashMode={flashMode}
                    cameraType={cameraType}
                    setFlashMode={this.setFlashMode}
                    setCameraType={this.setCameraType}
                    onCaptureIn={this.handleCaptureIn}
                    onCaptureOut={this.handleCaptureOut}
                    onLongCapture={this.handleLongCapture}
                    onShortCapture={this.handleShortCapture}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react-native-camera and click multiple pictures in one go and add a button for done.